# Get data based on a specific year in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I currently use DATE_SUB to show results in a database. So for data dating back 2 months I will do;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

For data dating back 20 days, I will do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

And for data dating back 2 years, I will do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

What I can't figure out is how to get data for a specific year eg if I want data for 2015 only. How do I do that?

**NB. date column type is datetime**

Comment: wouldn't it be as simple as `WHERE date = '2015'`, no? or what am I not getting here?

Comment: Don't do that. Use `WHERE ``date`` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH`. (Sorry, I am struggling with the backticks... Just one of course).

Comment: what's the date column type? question's unclear

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no you can't use WHERE date = '2015' cause the column date is using the inbuilt MySQL datetime to insert the current date when you add an article.

Comment: had we / I known what the column type was to start with, I'd of answered this right off the bat; just see the answer below then.

Comment: thought it was common knowledge!!! @FunkFortyNiner. Now if you can kindly undo your down vote that would be great

Answer (score 3):

You could use year()

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year(date)  = 2015
```